# Regex para extrair conteúdo da string

Tags: php, string, regex

Boa noite pessoal,

Obrigado por visitarem e se propor a me ajudar.
Eu sou péssimo em regex por isso venho pedir a ajuda de vocês.

Eu tenho a seguinte string que pode variar também conforme exemplo:

```
string(49) "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%"
string(49) "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = 50.83/86= | Weight: 50.00%"
```

No primeiro caso mesmo sem o valor eu preciso coletar 00.00.

Preciso extrair em um array da seguinte forma:

```
$dados[ "date" ] = "02/12/2018"
$dados[ "markOK" ] = "50"
$dados[ "markTotal" ] = "86"
$dados[ "weight" ] = "50.00"
```

Outros exemplos de saída:

```
string(49) "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "06/11/2018 (Assessment 2) = 22.40/35=32.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(49) "04/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /60= | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "11/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 27.00/40=33.75 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "09/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 30.00/30=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "14/08/2018 (Assessment 2) = 31.00/40=38.75 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "19/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 63.00/72=43.75 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "17/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 45.00/45=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
string(59) "22/05/2018 (Assessment 2) = 11.00/55=10.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta com o código do que já tentou fazer para analisarmos.

Comment: @Sam eu não consegui desenvolver nenhum raciocínio em regex para a solução, somente usando substring, mas como os dados podem variar de posição o código quebrou =/

Comment: @GustavoFilgueiras Mesmo assim, é importante colocar o código que vc já tentou fazer e quais os erros que estão ocorrendo. E se a string pode mudar, seria interessante colocar também todas as possibilidades (ou se forem muitas, alguns exemplos seguidos de uma explicação sobre como ela pode variar). Por favor clique em **[edit]** e adicione estes detalhes. E sugiro que leia o **[tour]** e as páginas **[ask]** e **[mcve]** para entender melhor como devem ser as perguntas.

Comment: @Sam obrigado plea dica, eu editei com o outro exemplo que pode variar, mas na questão do código, eu realmente não obtive nenhum avanço, desculpe.

Comment: @Sam Eu **acho** que é no primeiro caso, no `/80` (como não tem o "50" antes da barra, então o valor deve ser zero). Pelo menos foi o que entendi...

Comment: @hkotsubo Exatamente isso meu camarada !

Comment: @Sam, pode ser 00 ou 00.00 é pq as vezes o valor também é quebrado na real, tipo: 50.43

Comment: @Sam editei também, desculpas

Comment: Desculpe não poder ajudar mais, mas vou ter que desligar agora. De qualquer forma, se a **única** variação é que o "50" antes da barra é opcional, acho que usar uma combinação de [`strpos`, `strrpos` e `substr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36690930) talvez seja mais fácil que regex. Mas se quiser mesmo usar regex, pode dar uma olhada em alguns tutoriais, como [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [esse](http://rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado man

Comment: No caso de `86=` vc quer apenas `86` (sem o `=`)... e no caso de `40=33.75`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não usaria regex para isso. Pode quebrar a string em array pelo espaço e fazer um `forEach` associando os valores:

```
<?
$string = "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%";
$array = explode(" ", $string);

forEach($array as $item){
   // verifica quantas barras "/" a string possui
   preg_match_all("~\/~", $item, $matches);

   // se tiver 2 barras é uma data
   if(sizeof($matches[0]) == 2){
      $dados[ "date" ] = $item;
   }

   if(sizeof($matches[0]) == 1){
      $mark = explode("/", $item);
      // se o primerio estiver vazio, retorna 00.00
      $dados[ "markOK" ] = $mark[0] ? $mark[0] : "00.00";
      $dados[ "markTotal" ] = $mark[1];
   }

   if(strrpos($item, "%")){
      $dados[ "weight" ] = str_replace("%", "", $item);
   }
}

var_dump($dados);
?>
```

O resultado é:

```
array(4) {
  ["date"] => "02/12/2018"
  ["markOK"] => "00.00"
  ["markTotal"] => "86="
  ["weight"]=> "50.00"
}
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/dKTdxT)**

Comment: está perfeito :)
Somente na posicao do array["makrTotal"], está vindo com o sinal de igual

Comment: Só fazer um replace: `str_replace("=", "", $mark[1])`

Comment: obrigado man funcionou 100%

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso você precisará utilizar grupos em *regex* para delimitar e também identificar o que você quer procurar/extrair, os grupos são identificados pelo uso de elementos entre parênteses.

Este programa usa as amostras que você colocou na pergunta como base e como a expressão regular ficou (bastante) longa eu separei em pedaços menores para que fique mais fácil de ler e entender (como também de ajustar):

```
<?php

    $sampleData = array(
        "02/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /86= | Weight: 50.00%",
        "06/11/2018 (Assessment 2) = 22.40/35=32.00 | Weight: 50.00%",
        "04/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /60= | Weight: 50.00%",
        "11/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 27.00/40=33.75 | Weight: 50.00%",
        "09/09/2018 (Assessment 2) = 30.00/30=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%",
        "14/08/2018 (Assessment 2) = 31.00/40=38.75 | Weight: 50.00%",
        "19/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 63.00/72=43.75 | Weight: 50.00%",
        "17/06/2018 (Assessment 2) = 45.00/45=50.00 | Weight: 50.00%",
        "22/05/2018 (Assessment 2) = 11.00/55=10.00 | Weight: 50.00%"
    );

    $regex = '/$'.                          // começo da linha
        '([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})'.   // 99/99/9999 (obrigatório) [1]
        ' \(Assessment.+\)'.                // " (Assessment *) " -- ignorado
        ' = '.                              // " = " -- ignorado
        '([0-9.]{5})?'.                     // 99.99 (opcional) [2]
        '\/'.                               // "/" -- ignorado
        '([0-9]{2})?'.                      // 99 (opcional) [3]
        '='.                                // "=" -- ignorado                  
        '([0-9\.]{5})?'.                    // 99.99 (opcional) [4]
        '.+Weight: '.                       // "*Weight: " -- ignorado
        '([0-9\.]{5})'.                     // 99.99 (obrigatório) [5]
        '%$/';                              // "%" e termina a linha;

    foreach ($sampleData as $i){
        preg_match($regex, $i, $matchList);
        print_r($matchList);
    }

?>
```

No final, o laço `foreach()` no final pega o *array* item a item, aplica a *regex* e coloca o resultado da operação no *array* `$matchList`.

Aqui [e uma amostra do resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 04/12/2018 (Assessment 2) = /60= | Weight: 50.00%
    [1] => 04/12/2018
    [2] => 
    [3] => 60
    [4] => 
    [5] => 50.00
)
```

O primeiro item é sempre o que foi usado na consulta enquanto que os demais são aquilo que foi encontrado e em caso negativo ele ficará vazio.

Comment: O problema é que `[0-9.]{5}` também aceita `.....` e `..0..` como válidos, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/3ZXKNk/2). Se for para evitar esses casos, melhor ser um pouco mais preciso e usar algo como `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?`, que aceita `50` e `50.12`, [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/OWofBJ/1). E `{5}` limita a exatamente 5 caracteres, mas não sei se é o caso (não foi mencionado explicitamente se tem valores menores que 10 ou maiores que 99, mas eu só limitaria em exatamente 5 se tivesse certeza). Enfim, não dá pra saber só com base nos exemplos, mas é importante se atentar a esses detalhes :-)

Comment: Justamente, eu trabalhei com a amostra de dados e fiz algo que encaixasse, senão a _regex_ que já ficou longa ficaria maior ainda.